# Totalling up times from a mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, time, strtotime

I am trying to total up all the timesdate seperately from a few different columns in my database, however when the total for each surpasses 24 hours - I'm only getting 00:00 printed instead of the actual total.

I understand that the PHP date "H" variable only cover 00 - 23, so am unsure the best way to go about doing this. Any help would be much appreciated.

My SQL select code is:

```
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(lunch) ) ) AS lunch, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(overtime) ) ) AS overtime, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(day_paid) ) ) AS day_paid, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(lunch) ) ) AS lunch, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(holiday) ) ) AS holiday, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(absence) ) ) AS absence
```

My view code as an example for "lunch" is:

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime($day_breakdown->day_paid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL code you've written is fine, but the view code won't work as it's designed to work with dates/times and not with relative periods of time.

You should derive the hours/minutes by dividing the seconds out like this:

```
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60) % 60;
```

Comment: Just had to change my SQL slightly to "SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(lunch) ) AS lunch" by removing the SEC_TO_TIME section but works great now thanks :)